# Which verb form to use after "a sample of"?

Tags: grammar, verb-forms, subject-verb-agreement

> Consequently, a convenient sample of 360 drivers **was** recruited.
>   Consequently, a convenient sample of 360 drivers **were** recruited.

Which of these is the correct verb form?

Comment: It's "**a** sample"... right? Without "a convenient sample", it would be "360 drivers". Keep track of the subject and you'll find this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: thanks. but my question is about the "to be verb form", should I use was or were here?

Comment: ... You're asking whether the subject is singular or plural... which is what I have explained in my comment. You use "was" with singular subjects and you use "were" with plural subjects...

Comment: right, but I search google and I found this: a simple random of size n=200 drivers were ...

Comment: You can find many examples of poor English on the internet. That doesn't mean that it's correct... It's something that confuses a lot of people.

Answer (score 3):

The correct verb form to use is the singular: *was*. I hope to clarify why this is by displaying the grouping of words in the sentence:

> Consequently, a [convenient sample of 360 drivers] was recruited.

Although 360 drivers were involved in the sample, there was only a single sample, and that sample is the subject of the sentence. As there was only a single sample, the singular form *was* must be used.

You may find it easier to determine which verb form to use if you remove any modifiers from the subject:

> Consequently, a <s>convenient</s> sample <s>of 360 drivers</s> was recruited.
>   Consequently, a sample was recruited.

Here it is clear that the subject is singular.

---

As some potentially interesting trivia, some dialects (such as the [Yorkshire dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yorkshire_dialect)) don't strictly obey conjugation rules. If you live in a region that uses a dialect like this, you are likely to hear *were* used instead.

In other cases, it can be perfectly correct to use *were* where you may expect *was*. For these cases, you may be interested in reading about the [English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Distinguishing_from_past_indicative_after_if).